# JSC is empty when creating spark DataFrame

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to learn spark so don't judge harshly. I have the following problem. I can run spark basic examples like this one

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = '/g/scb/patil/andrejev/python36/bin/python3'
import random
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import *
sc.stop()
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('').setMaster('spark://remotehost:7789').setSparkHome('/path/to/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/') 
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf) 

num_samples = 100
def inside(p):
    x, y = random.random(), random.random()
    return x*x + y*y < 1

count = sc.parallelize(range(0, num_samples)).filter(inside).count()
pi = 4 * count / num_samples
print(pi)
```

but when I am creating data frame I have error that _jsc is NULL

```
eDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(a=1, intlist=[1,2,3], mapfield={"a": "b"})])  
/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/traceback_utils.py in __enter__(self)
     70     def __enter__(self):
     71         if SCCallSiteSync._spark_stack_depth == 0:
---> 72             self._context._jsc.setCallSite(self._call_site)
     73         SCCa._spark_stack_depth += 1
```

Here are the environemnt variables that are set on local machine

```
SPARK_HOME': '/usr/local/spark/    
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON: '/usr/bin/python3'
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS: 'notebook'
PYSPARK_PYTHON: '/g/scb/patil/andrejev/python36/bin/python3'
PATH': '...:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin:/usr/local/spark/bin'
```

and on remote machine

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=/g/scb/patil/andrejev/python36/bin/python3
PYSPARK_DIRVER_PYTHON=/g/scb/patil/andrejev/python36/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I figured out that I had two sessions (one default and one that I created) running in the same time. I ended explicitly using my session to create DataFrame.

```
sess = SparkSession(sc)
freq_signal = sess.createDataFrame([Row(a=1, intlist=[1,2,3], mapfield={"a": "b"})])
```